# How can I check if my pm2 app NODE_ENV is getting set?

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

So I just deployed a site with node and pm2 for the first time and I'm going back and doing some optimization and reading best practices, etc.

I read that you can get a lot of benefit by setting `NODE_ENV=production`.

I found this in the pm2 docs:

```
[process.json]
"env_production" : {
  "NODE_ENV": "production"
}

...

$ pm2 start process.json --env production
```

So, I did it but I have no idea if it is working. While trying to figure out how to check it I learned to try:

```
$ node
> process.env.NODE_ENV
> undefined
```

So, that's not a good sign.. but, with my limited understanding of how the low level stuff works, I can guess that maybe pm2 launches each app as a separate node process? So maybe I'm not in the right process when I try to check it.

Also, I don't know if I have to make a new ~/.pm2/dump.pm2 file because maybe whenever that is maybe overriding the options I set? (because I used `pm2 startup`).

How do I check if my pm2 app's NODE_ENV is set?

Comment: $ node
> process.env.NODE_ENV
will show you nothing because in this case you run pure node, not pm2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

***To answer the actual question in the title:***

Within your script, for me my Express app's `app.js` file, you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` to get the current value of `NODE_ENV` and log that out if you want.

An even better way is to use PM2's Process Metrics module, aka `pmx`.

```
yarn add pmx
```

or

```
npm install pmx --save
```

then

```
const Probe = require('pmx').probe()

Probe.metric({
  name    : 'NODE_ENV',
  value   : function() {
    return process.env.NODE_ENV
  }
})
```

Now it will show up in calls to pm2 monit (bottom left).

---

***To change your environment:***

It is necessary that you kill and restart the process to change your environment.

```
$ pm2 kill && pm2 start pm2.json --env production
```

The following isn't good enough:

```
pm2 restart pm2.json --env production
```

Comment: You should know that you are a savior @Zuko. You `pm2 kill`ed it, and that was absolutely necessary.

Comment: How do you set custom env variables in pm2 production? For eg. I want to set process.env.MONGODB_URI.

Comment: @FlynSequeira You can do that in your config file (this can be a .json file like the pm2.json in my example or in the docs they call it the ecosystem file: ecosystem.config.js). https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/ecosystem-file/ . There is probably a way to do this in the CLI as well, just look at the CLI page of the docs.

Comment: `pm2 kill` is that what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 12):

You can also check your `NODE_ENV` via running `pm2 show <yourServerName>`. This will output info about your running server including `node env`.

In addition, you can check your environment variables via running `pm2 env 0`. This will show all the environment variables for the running node process.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It explains how to use the commands of `pm2` to show all environment variables for a running app.

Answer (score 6):

Start it with `npm` by adding this to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "myScript": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start server.js"
}
```

Then

```
npm start myScript
```

You can do it directly too, but this is easy to manage, automate wth `crontab` and is in your source control...

Comment: Thanks for the "NODE_ENV=production" part at the beggining!  It works with "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start npm -- start" directly in the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

Your process.json file is incomplete. Try using something like this:

```
[process.json]
{
  "name" : "MyApp",
  "script" : "myapp.js",
  "env_production" : {
    "NODE_ENV": "production"
  }
}
```

Then add logging into your code, preferably somwhere on startup:

```
console.log("NODE_ENV : ", process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Now start the application:

```
pm2 start process.json --env production
```

Lastly watch app logs:

```
pm2 logs MyApp
```

This should do it.

Comment: No, I had a complete json config file, that was just a snippet.

Answer (score 3):

May be at the start of your server script you can print the value of the environment variable and then check the PM2 logs. Use the following code to print your environment variable value:

```
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV:', process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

And then use the following code to see the PM2 logs

pm2 logs app_name

Here `app_name` is your process name as indicated by the entry in the `process.json` file.

Comment: OK, I tried that and I still get undefined. So what am I doing wrong? Should I try to wipe my startup script and start over?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Environment variable for pm2 specifically.

go to `/etc/systemd/system/` location.
you can see a file named `pm2-username.service`
file. (eg: pm2-root.service ) you can directly add an Enviorment variable for pm2.
for me, it was **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** . so I added the line as below after the PATH variable.

```
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/lib......
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_1
```

after that, you can restart or start the node application with update-env flag,

```
pm2 start yourapp --update-env
```

Comment: Out of interest, why did you prefer setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to using `ldconfig` as shown in the [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst_zip)?  Using `ldconfig` can save various hassles.

Answer (score 0):

try `pm2 env <app_name/id>` also you can find NODE_ENV in `pm2 show <app_name/id>`

Answer (score -4):

In your terminal just type:

`echo NODE_ENV`

it will print current selected environment variable